# How do I make the canonical PROC CALIS LINEQS example work?

Tags: sas

I'm trying out the PROC CALIS LINEQS example outlined [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_calis_sect005.htm) (it works when I use the PATH and RAM examples) using the [Wheaton dataset](http://stat.utexas.edu/images/SSC/Site/wheaton-generated.zip) (I've renamed the headers to match the code below) with this code:

```
proc calis nobs=932 data=Wheaton;
   lineqs 
      Anomie67     = 1.0    * f_Alien67 + E1,
      Powerless67  = 0.833  * f_Alien67 + E2,
      Anomie71     = 1.0    * f_Alien71 + E3,
      Powerless71  = 0.833  * f_Alien71 + E4,
      Education    = 1.0    * f_SES     + E5,
      SEI          = lambda * f_SES     + E6,
      f_Alien67    = gamma1 * f_SES     + D1,
      f_Alien71    = gamma2 * f_SES     + beta * Alien67 + D2;
   std
      E1           = theta1,
      E2           = theta2,
      E3           = theta1,
      E4           = theta2,
      E5           = theta3,
      E6           = theta4,
      D1           = psi1,
      D2           = psi2,
      f_SES        = phi;
   cov
      E1  E3       = theta5,
      E2  E4       = theta5;
run;
```

but I get this error:

> "Predictor variable Alien67 in the equation with outcome variable f_Alien71 is neither a manifest, an F, an E, nor a D variable."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

okay, I found the error - I had to consult [page 450](http://www.math.wpi.edu/saspdf/stat/chap19.pdf) of the [SAS OnlineDoc™: Version 8](http://www.math.wpi.edu/saspdf/) to find the solution which is basically to change this line of code:

```
f_Alien71    = gamma2 * f_SES     + beta * Alien67 + D2;
```

to

```
f_Alien71    = gamma2 * f_SES     + beta * f_Alien67 + D2;
```

I got a clue when I was reading page 450 because V5 in the book which corresponds to SEI in the code was using F3 (which was f_SES) as an input and then I noticed that the input to F2 in the book (which was f_Alien71 in the code) was F1 (which was f_Alien67 in the code) and I found that there was a mismatch.

[image]